# How to use Async task for different values.I will explain my problem briefly in description

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-asynctask, android-volley

[image]I am getting retrieved data from server using volley and display in the list view. So I will get client's address  from server and I need to calculate the distance between current location of the person who is using the app to the address which I got from the server.I will get different clients address and i need to calculate all their distances and display seperately in listview along with clients name.So I am using the following code.I am getting the same distance for all the clients as show in the image.there are places,thane,delhi,kalyan.I need to calculate the distance from current location to those places.I dont understand what the problem is. code for calculating distance using AyncTask.this code is inside fragment.

```
public class getLocationFromNameAsync extends 
  AsyncTask<String  ,String,Double> {
    Context context;
    onTaskCompleted completed;

    public getLocationFromNameAsync(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.completed = (onTaskCompleted) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());

        List<Address> address1=null;
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            address1 = coder.getFromLocationName(district, 5);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address1 == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fetching Location,Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        final Address location11 = address1.get(0);
        location11.getLatitude();
        location11.getLongitude();
        if (checkPermission()) {
            LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                latti = location.getLatitude();
                longi = location.getLongitude();
            } else if (location1 != null) {
                latti = location1.getLatitude();
                longi = location1.getLongitude();
            } else if (location2 != null) {
                latti = location2.getLatitude();
                longi = location2.getLongitude();
            }
            coder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = coder.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    area = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String county = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String postal_code = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    fullAddress=address+","+area+","+city+","+county+","+postal_code;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        LatLng source = new LatLng(latti, longi);

        LatLng destination = new LatLng(location11.getLatitude(), location11.getLongitude());
        double dis= SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(source,destination);
        dis/=1000;
        return dis;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Double aDouble) {
       completed.onTaskComplete(aDouble);
    }
}
```

my interface code.

```
public interface onTaskCompleted {
public void onTaskComplete(Double result);
}
```

navigationDrawerActivity code.In this activity,I am getting result.

```
public class navigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener ,onTaskCompleted{
  static double distance;
 @Override
public void onTaskComplete(Double result) {
    distance=result;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result is "+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Getting data from API and setting data in listView

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getTaskUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("dataObj");
                        int length=ja.length();

                        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
                            JSONObject temp = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                           nameC= temp.getString("name");
                           checkId=temp.getString("clientEid");
                           clientName=temp.getString("client");
                           candidateFatherName=temp.getString("fatherName");
                           clientProcess=temp.getString("otherId");
                            dueDate=temp.getString("deadline");
                            JSONArray jsaDate = temp.getJSONArray("updateDetails");
                            for(int k=0; k<jsaDate.length(); k++){
                                JSONObject jo1 = jsaDate.getJSONObject(k);
                                sentDate = jo1.getString("date");
                            }

                            JSONArray ja1 = temp.getJSONArray("address");
                            for(int j=0; j<ja1.length(); j++){
                                JSONObject jo1 = ja1.getJSONObject(j);
                                landmark=jo1.getString("landmark");
                                district= jo1.getString("district");
                                userAddrss=jo1.getString("full");

                                Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                                       new getLocationFromNameAsync(getContext()).execute(district);

                                arrayList.add(new DataModel(nameC,district,landmark,checkId,Math.floor((navigationDrawer.distance*100)/100),clientName,candidateFatherName,clientProcess,sentDate,dueDate));
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: You miss a loop trough all items and setting it to the model, not the view there, you will override always with the latest value calculated

Comment: I didn’t get you. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

@MarconVasconcelos is saying that you need to iterate all your list items, and for each  of them apply the response received